# no output for scala bindgen

Tags: scala, scala-bindgen

I built scala-bindgen under ubuntu 16.04 using libclang3.8 , the executable is produced and runs:

```
xxx@xxx:~/bin/scala-bindgen$ ./bindgen/target/scala-2.11/bindgen-out
// argc=1
// argv[0]=bindgen
// _argc=1
arg_files         :
clang_args        :
link              :
output            : --undefined--
match             : --undefined--
builtins          : false
clang_ast         : false
override_enum_type: --undefined--
ctypes_prefix     : --undefined--
use_core          : false
remove_prefix     : --undefined--
no_scala_enums    : false
```

but no output is produced when running it against the example header

```
xxx@xxx:~/bin/scala-bindgen$ ./bindgen/target/scala-2.11/bindgen-out -emit-clang-ast -o getopt.scala test/getopt.h 
// argc=5
// argv[0]=bindgen
// argv[1]=-emit-clang-ast
// argv[2]=-o
// argv[3]=getopt.scala
// argv[4]=test/getopt.h
// _argc=5
arg_files         : test/getopt.h
clang_args        :
link              :
output            : getopt.scala
match             : it-clang-ast
builtins          : false
clang_ast         : true
override_enum_type: --undefined--
ctypes_prefix     : --undefined--
use_core          : false
remove_prefix     : --undefined--
no_scala_enums    : false
--> Processing file: /home/xxx/bin/scala-bindgen/test/getopt.h
1
index: 14ec4a0
2
unit: c4004ac0
3
4
5
6
Done.
```

No output is produced (stdout or file both tested)

```
xxx@xxx:~/bin/scala-bindgen$ ls
bindgen  build.sbt  LICENSE  project  README.md  target  test
```

What am I doing wrong ?